# Python Assistance

Tags: python

I need to extract file names with an extention of .exe from a file named files.txt, the below grep command works fine within the terminal window but for the exercise I'm working on I need it to be completed with a python script.

I have done some reading and I cant quite grasp it, I apperciate I am asking for someone to give me the answer however if you could explain the process of the script too that would be a huge help in me getting my head round this.

example line from file -

```
10.10.10.10 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:11:14 -0700] "GET /include/somefile.exe HTTP/1.1" 200 25139 "somewebsite.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31" "www.somewebsite.com"
```

Working Grep Command:

```
grep ".exe" files.txt | awk -F "/include/" '{print $2}' | cut -d "H" -f 1 | sort -u
```

I need the final output to be just a list of file names i.e. myfile.exe, myfile2.exe

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and **code to reproduce it**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What Python code have you got so far? [It appears no attempt was made.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need

```py
import re
# Opening and reading file 
text = ''
with open("files.txt", 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

names = re.findall(r'/(\w+\.exe)', text)
print(names)
```

Or you can do it as follow

```py
import re
# Opening and reading file 
text = ''
with open("files.txt", 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

names = []
delimiter = "/"
# iteration through all occurs of ".exe" sub-string 
for m in re.finditer('.exe', text):
    a = m.start()
    c = text[a]
    i = a
    # Finding previous '/' character's location
    while (c != delimiter):
        i -= 1
        c = text[i]
    # Adding sub-string containing .exe file name to list 
    # i is index of '/' character 
    # a is index of '.exe' sub-string
    names.append(text[i+1:a+4])
print(names)
```

For inputing

```
10.10.10.10 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:11:14 -0700] "GET /include/somefile.exe"]
10.10.10.10 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:11:14 -0700] "GET /include/somefileother.exe"]
```

it will show Output

```
['somefile.exe', 'somefileother.exe']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
import re

x = '10.10.10.10 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:11:14 -0700] "GET /include/somefile.exe HTTP/1.1" 200 25139 "somewebsite.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31" "www.somewebsite.com"'
x = re.sub(r".*?/include/(.*?)\s.*", r"\1", x)
print(x)
#somefile.exe
```

Comment: This can only detect one .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the rules you want in place to match a filename. If it will be preceded by a forward slash character and always have the .exe extension, then:

```
input = '10.10.10.10 - - [25/Apr/2013:14:11:14 -0700] "GET /include/somefile.exe HTTP/1.1" 200 25139 "somewebsite.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31" "www.somewebsite.com"'

import re

matchObj = re.search(r'/(\w+\.exe)', input)
if matchObj:
    print(matchObj.group(1))
```

A more generic rule that will match any filename (without the preceding forward slash), but with a three character extension might be:

```
matchObj = re.search(r'(\w+\.\w{3})', input)
if matchObj:
    print(matchObj.groups())
```

The above only matches `somefile.exe` and not the website URLs because the URLs have a double quote at the end `.com"`, and because of the double quote, it doesn't match the above rule.